# External JavaScript validations are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my external JavaScript file and functions - validations.js

```
function validateEmail() {
    var x = document.forms["Register"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}

function validate(){
{
    var a=document.forms["Register"]["name"].value;
    var b=document.forms["Register"]["email"].value;
    var c=document.forms["Register"]["password"].value;
    //var d=document.forms["Form"]["answer_d"].value;
    if (a==null || a=="",b==null || b=="",c==null || c=="")
      {
      alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
      return false;
      }
    }
}
```

And this is my HTML file

```
<body>
    <h3>User Registration Form</h3>
    <form name ="Register" onsubmit="return validate() && validateEmail();" method="POST" action="RegisterServlet">
        <table align="center" cellpadding = "10">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="30"/>
                    (max 30 characters a-z and A-Z)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="100" /></td>
            </tr>    
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="password" maxlength="100" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <script src="validations.js"></script>
</body>
```

These are the other onsubmit code I tried

```
onsubmit="return!!(validate() & validateEmail())"
onsubmit="return(validate() && validateEmail())"
onsubmit="return validate() && validateEmail()"
```

When I put the JavaScript in the same page, it's working.

Comment: what error you get in console?

Comment: how are you including your external js in your html?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors.validations are simply not working. and i'm including javascript in the body <script src="validations.js"></script> and i tried on the header too

Comment: Is the source link correct? Perhaps that file cannot be found in that location?

Comment: Both html and javascript are in the same folder and when i tried with one function its working but when i try multiple functions its not working.

Comment: Hey everybody thanks for the questions and support. Now its working. It was something problem with the server. After i stop the servers and reopened and ran the application. Now its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey everybody thanks for the questions and support. Now its working. It was something problem with the server. After i stop the servers and reopened and ran the application. Now its working.